# Python code coverage missing when files have the same name

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage

I'm using pytest and pytest-cov for code coverage.

My project looks as following. There're two modules `services` and `workers`.

```
python_tmp
├── tests
│   └── some_test.py
├── services
│   └── utils.py
└── workers
    └── utils.py
```

Both of them have `utils.py` inside. But the content are different.

services/utils.py

```
def function_1():
    return 1
```

and workers/utils.py

```
def function_2():
    return 2
```

In `tests/some_test.py` you can find the test cases.

```
import pytest
import services.utils as t1
import workers.utils as t2

def test_function_1():
    res = t1.function_1()
    assert res == 1

def test_function_2():
    res = t2.function_2()
    assert res == 2
```

If I run the test `python -m pytest -v tests --cov=services --cov=workers --cov-report=xml:coverage.xml`, it will generate following report. But you can see there's only one `utils.py` been reported, and there's ambiguity that you don't know which module it belongs to.

```
...
    <sources>
        <source>/Users/xxxxxxx/workspace/tmp/python_tmp/services</source>
        <source>/Users/xxxxxxx/workspace/tmp/python_tmp/workers</source>
    </sources>
    <packages>
        <package branch-rate="0" complexity="0" line-rate="1" name=".">
            <classes>
                <class branch-rate="0" complexity="0" filename="utils.py" line-rate="1" name="utils.py">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines>
                        <line hits="1" number="1"/>
                        <line hits="1" number="2"/>
                    </lines>
                </class>
            </classes>
        </package>
    </packages>
</coverage>
```

How to fix it? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is mentioned [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov/issues/289)

So to fix this you can run `python -m pytest -v tests --cov --cov-report=xml:coverage.xml`.

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Probably `--cov=.`, AFAIR it requires a value.

Comment: I have ran it on my system to test. It works fine. (Don't add the '=' sign)

Comment: I have ran it on my system too. `--cov` without an argument indeed works (I recall it didn't work earlier, though), but also includes `pytest` and plugins sources in the report, which is hardly desirable.

Comment: What's your suggestion to ignore folders, as `--cov` will include all the folders in current dir. Create a `.coveragerc` file and omit there ? Thanks!

Comment: From the link mentioned in my answer it says that this error was not reproduced in version 2.2.0 but rolling back to such an old version will invite other errors. I guess the best bet would be .coveragerc file modification.